# HTML position:absolute, e-mail signature

Tags: html, css, signature

I know that probably position will not work on many platforms as an e-mail signature, but I want to fix another problem: when I start typing text in the e-mail, the text slowly goes bellow the signature, instead of "pushing" it away to the bottom (he text gathers over it and not above it). How can I fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHY5c.png)

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>sig-noborders</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:1312px; height:612px;">
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_01.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:1312px; height:126px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_02.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:126px; width:146px; height:486px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_03.png~original); position:absolute; left:146px; top:126px; width:374px; height:370px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_04.png); position:absolute; left:520px; top:126px; width:160px; height:255px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="http://benjaminjayshand.com" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_05.png~original); position:absolute; left:680px; top:126px; width:31px; height:30px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_06.png); position:absolute; left:711px; top:126px; width:601px; height:3px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_07.png); position:absolute; left:711px; top:129px; width:59px; height:252px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="http://benjaminjayshand.com" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_08.png~original); position:absolute; left:770px; top:129px; width:352px; height:25px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_09.png); position:absolute; left:1122px; top:129px; width:190px; height:167px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_10.png); position:absolute; left:770px; top:154px; width:352px; height:58px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_11.png); position:absolute; left:680px; top:156px; width:31px; height:53px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_12.png); position:absolute; left:680px; top:209px; width:2px; height:84px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="http://designtel.co" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_13.png~original); position:absolute; left:682px; top:209px; width:27px; height:29px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_14.png); position:absolute; left:709px; top:209px; width:2px; height:84px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="http://designtel.co" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_15.png~original); position:absolute; left:770px; top:212px; width:220px; height:25px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_16.png); position:absolute; left:990px; top:212px; width:132px; height:84px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_17.png); position:absolute; left:770px; top:237px; width:220px; height:59px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_18.png); position:absolute; left:682px; top:238px; width:27px; height:55px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_19.png); position:absolute; left:680px; top:293px; width:1px; height:88px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/benjaminjayshand/" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_20.png~original); position:absolute; left:681px; top:293px; width:30px; height:31px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_21.png); position:absolute; left:770px; top:296px; width:3px; height:86px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/designtel" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_22.png~original); position:absolute; left:773px; top:296px; width:236px; height:25px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_23.png); position:absolute; left:1009px; top:296px; width:33px; height:5px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/designtel" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_24.png~original); position:absolute; left:1042px; top:296px; width:127px; height:25px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_25.png); position:absolute; left:1169px; top:296px; width:143px; height:316px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_26.png); position:absolute; left:1009px; top:301px; width:9px; height:81px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_27.png~original); position:absolute; left:1018px; top:301px; width:13px; height:14px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_28.png); position:absolute; left:1031px; top:301px; width:11px; height:81px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_29.png); position:absolute; left:1018px; top:315px; width:13px; height:67px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_30.png); position:absolute; left:773px; top:321px; width:236px; height:61px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_31.png); position:absolute; left:1042px; top:321px; width:127px; height:61px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_32.png); position:absolute; left:681px; top:324px; width:30px; height:57px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_33.png); position:absolute; left:520px; top:381px; width:159px; height:231px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="mailto:info@benjaminjayshand.com">
     <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_34.png~original); position:absolute; left:679px; top:381px; width:33px; height:27px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_35.png); position:absolute; left:712px; top:381px; width:58px; height:1px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_36.png); position:absolute; left:712px; top:382px; width:57px; height:89px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="mailto:info@benjaminjayshand.com">
     <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_37.png~original); position:absolute; left:769px; top:382px; width:340px; height:25px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_38.png); position:absolute; left:1109px; top:382px; width:60px; height:230px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_39.png); position:absolute; left:769px; top:407px; width:340px; height:62px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_40.png); position:absolute; left:679px; top:408px; width:33px; height:63px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_41.png); position:absolute; left:769px; top:469px; width:1px; height:143px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_42.png~original); position:absolute; left:770px; top:469px; width:156px; height:19px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_43.png); position:absolute; left:926px; top:469px; width:183px; height:143px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_44.png); position:absolute; left:679px; top:471px; width:1px; height:9px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_45.png~original); position:absolute; left:680px; top:471px; width:33px; height:8px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_46.png); position:absolute; left:713px; top:471px; width:56px; height:141px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_47.png); position:absolute; left:680px; top:479px; width:33px; height:1px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_48.png~original); position:absolute; left:679px; top:480px; width:11px; height:6px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_49.png); position:absolute; left:690px; top:480px; width:12px; height:132px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/sig-noborders_50.png~original); position:absolute; left:702px; top:480px; width:11px; height:6px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_51.png); position:absolute; left:679px; top:486px; width:11px; height:126px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_52.png); position:absolute; left:702px; top:486px; width:11px; height:126px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_53.png); position:absolute; left:770px; top:488px; width:156px; height:124px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(sig-noborders_54.png); position:absolute; left:146px; top:496px; width:374px; height:116px;" title="">
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `position: relative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the text is overlapping/going below the signature due to the mass absolute positioning of elements within the html signature.

i'd strongly recommend using simpler html table's as you will be able to achieve the desired layout as well as a cross client solution.